# Kusto calculation with Loop

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql, kusto-explorer

I am trying to make an iterative calculation, but it seems that it is not possible, has someone any clue if there is a workaround?

How my Table looks like:

| Column1 | Column2 | Todo |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | B | 0.5 |
| A | C | -0.3 |
| A | C | -0.3 |

What I want to see:

| Column1 | Column2 | Todo | Calculated |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | B | 0.5 | 1.0 |
| A | C | -0.3 | 0.7 |
| A | C | -0.3 | 0.6 |

Starting variable is 0.5, it would add 0.5 in the first row. In the second row it would substract the result from the first row. If the calculation is below Zero it has to set the result to 0.0

Would be great the have help here.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the sort order in your example? when do you restart this calculation? Since Kusto does not preserve order. the question as it is written now does not make much sense.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what I understood, it looks like you're trying to get the cumulative sum of a column. You could use [row_cumsum()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/rowcumsumfunction) after setting the right sort order:

```
let T = datatable(Column1:string, Column2:string, Todo:double)
[
   "A", "B", 0.5,
   "A", "C", -0.3,
   "A", "C", -0.3,
];
T
| sort by Column1
| serialize Calculated = row_cumsum(Todo) + 0.5
```

I didn't get how the last row in your example ended up as 0.7 - 0.3 = 0.6? Shouldn't it be 0.4?